# Delongi Eletta Usage

Tags: equipment

I've just purchased a Eletta Cappuccino ECAM 44.660.B and have a few questions if anyone owns one here?

1. Whats the best way to get a large mug/Americano out of it? I'm used to Chemex coffee and being able to have ~250ml of coffee easily! I tried a 'my coffee' preset to almost fill my mug but it tasted too weak?
2. Whats a long coffee? I tried it and it appears to be two shots and tasted very strong!
3. How do I get a single espresso shot?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Robin, welcome to Coffee SE, please feel free to take the [tour](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I don't own the machine, but I've checked its pictures on the Internet at a glance.*

1. As far as I understand, the definition you've made is called **Coffè Crema** and discussed under [this question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/i-run-my-espresso-machine-until-my-whole-cup-is-full-whats-my-coffee-called) along with **Coffè Lungo**. In some bean-to-cup machines you may set the details how each button prepares each kind of coffee. If this is not the case, I can see that the machine has capability of preparing two espresso at once. So, you may try to prepare a **Doppio** (double espresso) to make a stronger beverage. Here is a quick [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppio).
2. See the link in the previous item.
3. There should be a button for that on such machines. At least, I hope there is one.

Comment: Thanks! So, in answer to 3, the manual describes it as 'Short at 40mm' and 'Standard at 60' - is that espresso?

And then, to make an Americano, is it two shots of 'short', then top with water up to around ~190ml?

Comment: @Robin Edwards, An espresso consists of 25–30 ml of water and sometimes called _short black_. It is discussed [here](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/doppio-vs-short-black-whats-the-difference/2747#2747).

Comment: @Robin Edwards, For Americano, please check [this thread](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2580/americano-water-before-the-shot). The exact amount of water is not the most important concern, but 190 ml should do in case of Americano. You can check [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffè_Americano) for details of this.

Answer (score 1):

After owning the same machine for a week and googling your same queries a few times I thought I'd post the answer I came up with (even though your question is a few years old at this stage):

1. Press and hold the "long" coffee button for ~10 seconds until "program quantity" appears on screen. Press any button to store that setting when it's filled up to the desired quantity (and "my coffee" in future to get that same amount). If you want a stronger coffee, fill to ~75% of the mug, store it, then press the single espresso shot button to the right. Even without that extra step, I can program my machine to fill a 300ml mug.

[image: coffee]

2. See, e.g. [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/end-result-of-americano-vs-long-black) or [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/i-run-my-espresso-machine-until-my-whole-cup-is-full-whats-my-coffee-called) (to me, an Americano/long coffee/cafe crema are all basically the same with varying levels of water added, but saying that makes me sound quite unrefined).
3. Use the single shot button indicated above with the red circle to get a single espresso shot.